Rationale of ADF (Augmented Dickey-Fuller) test for unit root
I would like to understand how the ADF  test  (Augmented Dickey-Fuller) indeed tests that there is no unit root in the characteristic equation. For me, it seems to only test if $1$ is a root or not, but does not test if there is a unit root different to $1$. Here is how I understand it.
Consider the $(p+1)$th-order autoregressive time series
$$y_t=\alpha_1y_{t-1}+\alpha_2y_{t-2}+\cdots+\alpha_{p+1}y_{t-p-1}+e_t$$ and its characteristic equation $$m^{p+1}-\alpha_1m^p-\alpha_2m^{p-1}-\cdots-\alpha_{p+1}=0,$$ for $m\in\mathbb{C}.$
If none of the characteristic roots are of module $1$, then $y_t$ is stationnary. If $1$ is a root of the characteristic equation then the sum of the autoregressive parameters is $1$ and we can reparametrize the model as
$$\Delta y_t=\delta y_{t-1}+\theta_1\Delta y_{t-1}+\cdots+\theta_p\Delta y_{t-p}+e_t,$$
where $\Delta y_t = y_t - y_{t-1}$, $\delta = \alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{p+1}-1$ and $\theta_k=-\alpha_{k+1}-\cdots-\alpha_{p+1}.$ So the ADF test consists to test wether or not $\delta = 0,$ but for me, by doing that we only test if $1$ is a root or not. So what can we tell about other unit roots by just testing $\delta = 0$ ? Because if there is a unit root, the sum of the autoregressive parameters is not necessary equal to $1$ if $p>0.$
Thank you for your answers !

I realized that if $m$ is a $n$-th root of unity which is a root of the characteristic equation $$\Phi(m)=m^{p+1}-\alpha_1 m^p-\cdots-\alpha_{p+1}=0,$$ then we also have
\begin{align*}
\Phi(1)=\Phi(m^n)=m^{n+p+1}-\alpha_1 m^{n+p}-\cdots -\alpha_{p+1}\times 1=m^n\Phi(m)=0,
\end{align*}
so the sum of the autoregressive coefficients is $1$.
